How do I determine causality and BIBO stability of an LTI discrete system that includes a fraction?
\begin{align} y[n+1] = \frac{x[n]}{x[n+1]} \end{align}
In this system I have a fraction that has a "component" that is shifted back, and the system entirely is shifted forward.
How do I determine causality, BIBO stability, and time variance?
This problem is particularly hard for me because I can't visualize how the system behaves, when it has a fraction of two signals of different time shifts.

What gives you the impression that it's linear?  Does it satisfy superposition?

Same as for any other system, honestly: you write the system down, you write the mathematical formulation of the thing you want to check down, and try to find a proof that it's causal, that it's BIBO stable, and time-invariant. How you do that depends on the system. In the end, the answer is "you apply the math you learned, in a creative manner".
Often it's easy to find a counter-example. For example, it's super easy here to find an example input $x$ that is bounded but makes  $y$ unbounded. For example, $x[0]=0, x[1] = 1$. Done; not BIBO stable.

I didn't understand your example, what does x[0]=0 x[1]=1 prove?

ah, sorry, I mean $x[0] = 1, x[1] = 0$.
